# Use CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath in MVC and WebPages 2

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages

In WebPages Razor v1 it's possible to call functions cross cshtml-pages using this syntax:

```
@{
    dynamic hlp = WebPage.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("/newhelper.cshtml");
}
@hlp.SomeHelper("foo")
```

The same is not possible in Razor v2 (null reference error). And not in MVC either (which is probably less surprising). I want to know if there's another way of doing the same in Razor v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the code shown in the question is not supported - it's just trying to simulate some logic that may or may not be equivalent to what really happens with Web Pages / Razor compilation.

Web Pages helpers should go in CSHTML files in `~/App_Code`. Code in there should be accessible to all other view pages in the app.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering. I added "hack" as a tag. I'm using RazorEngine and/or Roslyn for the purpose instead.

Comment: I went another direction - using RenderPage with a bit of sugar : http://joeriks.com/2013/03/06/displaytemplates-in-mvc-and-webpages-razor/